# Adjust Angular UI Boostrap Modal Size/Width

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Essentially what the title says - need to make this wider. Tried several solutions, neither work. Note that the "backdropClass" is applied perfectly and works, but the windowClass doesn't, nor the "size" option. I have tried them independently, nothing. CSS is in the same folder as the working backdrop class"

```
                        $modal.open({
                            templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
                            controller: 'controllingControllerCtrl',
                            backdrop: 'static',
                            backdropClass : 'blackBackgroundModal ' +
                                'blackBackgroundModal.fade blackBackgroundModal.fade.in',
                            windowClass: 'resizeModalWindow' +
                                'resizeModalDialog',
                            size: 'sm'
                                    });
                                }
                            }
```

CSS:

```
.resizeModalWindow .resizeModalDialog {
    width: 5000px; 
}
```

What needs to be done for at least the "size" option to register - I don't really need custom widths.

Edit: Forgot checked links!

[Checked this Q first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311736/how-do-i-increase-modal-width-in-angular-ui-bootstrap)

[Then this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704296/angular-ui-bootstrap-dialog-width)

[And of course docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: I see a `size:'sm'` doesn't that make it small ?

Comment: Does absolutely nothing. Tried 'lg' too.

Comment: size does work, it works for me... it adds the modal-sm or modal-lg classes to your modal-dialog class, you can add a plunker for us to see why it doesnt work for you...

Comment: In the end my controller was being cached somehow or something. I have no idea. It does indeed work. Wow, 2 hrs well wasted on my part.

Answer (score 1):

You should have white space  between those two classes will recognize by the css rule.

```
windowClass: 'resizeModalWindow ' +'resizeModalDialog',
                               ^^^added space here
```

Comment: Valid, but a result of type while changing values to example names. Unfortunately doesn't solve the problem. Good call though, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap css has media queries defining the width of a modal based on screen size. to globally overwrite them use `!important`

like this

```
.modal {
    size: 5000px !important;
}
```

Comment: We use a lot of modals in our application, I only need to resize one. In fact, it is not an option to resize all. That's good to know overall though, thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.resizeModalDialog .modal-dialog{
   width: 5000px; 
  }
```

Add the property where you instance the modal

```
windowClass:'resizeModalDialog',
```

windowClass will not resize another way.

Comment: You can see in comments OP figured it out.